# Gan in Keras - You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

Tags: keras, gan

i have a problem with the training of my GAN.

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonTest/main.py", line 172, in 
<module>
train(1)
File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonTest/main.py", line 145, in train
g_loss = gan.train_on_batch([[noise], word_as_sequence, [len(word)]], 
[valid_label])
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1217, in train_on_batch
outputs = self.train_function(ins)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
return self._call(inputs)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1458, in __call__
run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed 
a value for placeholder tensor 'ocr_input_img' with dtype float and shape 
[?,128,512,1]
 [[{{node ocr_input_img}}]]
```

my Code looks like the following:

```
...
img = self.generator([noise, word_embedded])


self.discriminator.trainable = False
self.text_recognition.trainable = False

valid = self.discriminator(img)

ctc = self.text_recognition([img, labels, label_length])

combined = Model([noise, word_sequence, labels, label_length], [ctc])
```

I cant understand what the problem with the text recognition is. The Discriminator have the same input shape  for the image as the text recognition. When i try to run it without the text_recognition and only with the Discriminator it works.

The Part to start Gan training:

```
g_loss = gan.train_on_batch([[noise], word_as_sequence, [len(word)]], [valid_label])
```

The Output of the Generator has the shape=(?, 128, 512, 1) dtype=float32

Comment: Please provide the full error trace.

Comment: I updated the Question with the full error